# A Proof About Annihilators and Linear Functionals

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

I'm following the proof of the fact that $ \mathrm{dim}(U) + \mathrm{dim} \mathrm{Ann}(U) = \mathrm{dim}(V) $ for $U \subset V$ and $\mathrm{Ann}(U)$ is an annihilator of $U$, in [here](http://books.google.com/books?id=NSXCaGSVaX4C&lpg=PR1&pg=PA52#v=onepage&q&f=false) (Proposition 2.20 (a)).

But I don't understand how $v^{'}(v_{i}) = c_{i}$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By definition of dual base
$$
v_i'(v_j) =
\begin{cases}
1 & \text{if } i = j\\
0 & \text{if } i\neq j
\end{cases}
$$
Now
$$
v'(v_i) = \sum_j c_j v_j'(v_i) = \sum_{j\neq i} c_j v_j'(v_i) + c_i v_i'(v_i) = c_i v_i'(v_i) = c_i
$$